# View old changes to gcc cvs repository?

Tags: gcc, cvs

I'd like to view the patches from https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=18804, but the links http://gcc.gnu.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/gcc/gcc/ChangeLog.diff?cvsroot=gcc&r1=2.6712&r2=2.6713 and http://gcc.gnu.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/gcc/gcc/mklibgcc.in.diff?cvsroot=gcc&r1=1.77&r2=1.78 are now dead.

From the information there how can I access https://gcc.gnu.org/viewvc/gcc/ (or cvs directly instead of through the web viewer) and find the patches?

Comment: I found it through binary search https://gcc.gnu.org/viewvc/gcc?view=revision&revision=91732 , but is there a better way?

Comment: It looks to me like gcc moved from CVS to SVN some time ago, but did not spend the time to convert the comments in their bugzilla. This would be a question for the gcc maintainers, but I suspect that binary search is the way to go.